# I'm trying to turn this php function into a javascript function

Tags: php, javascript

I have a PHP function to create an address from the data retrieved from the database. I want to use the same feature to make a JavaScript function that will do the same. What it does is take the field and if it is empty it does nothing but if there is data then it will append ", " a comma and space.

```
$parts = array(
          $club['clubAdd1'],
          $club['clubAdd2'],
          $club['clubCity'],
          $club['clubCounty'],
          $club['clubPostcode'],
        );

$address = array();

foreach ($parts as $part){
    if ('' != $part){
        $address[] = $part;
    }
}

$address = implode(', ', $address);
```

My current attempt is the function is called everytime the keyup is preformed on the form fields (test purposes only)

```
function autoAddress(){
var address = "";
var address1 = document.address.address1.value;
var address2 = document.address.address2.value;
var city = document.address.city.value;
var county = document.address.county.value;
var postcode = document.address.postcode.value;

var parts = new array[
        address1,
        address2,
        city,
        county,
        postcode
      ];
var testAddress = new array();
foreach(parts as part){
  if ('' != part){
    testAddress[] = part;
  }
}
testAddress = array.join(', ', testAddress);
alert(testAddress);
```

}

Comment: JavaScript uses [Array.join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to do what `implode` does in PHP. Otherwise, just concatenate strings using `+`

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I think your last variable doesn't need a comma. `$club['clubPostcode'],` Try removing the comma.

Comment: What is your attemt so far? I don't see any javascript code

Comment: Edited code to show what i have so far.

Comment: in `foreach(parts as part)`, `part` will contain a numeric index of the current entry in `parts`, you have to use `parts[part]` to access it.

Comment: @Fred That's irrelevant to the question. You're trying to tell him how to fix working code.

Comment: there is no foreach loop in javascript (considering the way you're using it here); http://goo.gl/LOzO4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var parts = [
          club['clubAdd1'],
          club['clubAdd2'],
          club['clubCity'],
          club['clubCounty'],
          club['clubPostcode']
        ];

var address = [];

for (var i=0; i<=parts.length; i++){
    if (parts[i]){
        address.push(parts[i]);
    }
}

var joined = address.join(', ');
```

Comment: `var joined = address.join(', ', address);`? `join` only uses one argument.

Comment: Thanks, works minus one thing. The comma is being appended to the end even if there is no more data. Tired it here but keyup mightnt do alerts in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/NmSBC/

Comment: Yeah, edited the if statement, no comma in the end now. It happened because the last value in the array parts was accually "undefined" and it WAS different then '';